# Rsync over SSH - timeout in ssh or rsync?

Tags: ssh, timeout, rsync

I'm dealing with a crappy ISP that resets my WAN connection at random points while my script is running. I want the transfer to survive this reset and go on. I manually launch this script vs using cron / launchd currently.

I have a fairly basic script as shown below:

```
rsync -rltv --progress --partial -e "ssh -i <key> -o ConnectTimeout=300" <remotedir> <localdir>
```

Am I better off putting the timeout in the rsync section instead?

For example:

```
rsync -rltv --progress--partial --timeout=300 -e "ssh -i <key>" <remotedir> <localdir>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

`ConnectTimeout` only applies when SSH is trying to establish the connection with the server, it doesn't have anything to do with timeouts during the data transfer. So you need to use the `--timeout` option to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-running the rsync. Also try without the ssh option. The job failed probably due to losing your network connection. I have an rsync job copying files between datacenters running every 2 hours via cron and it will fail about once per day.